# SQL select with two conditions

Tags: sql

```
+------+-----------------+-------+
| TEAM |      VISITS     | MEDAL |
+------+-----------------+-------+
|  1   |    02/02/2021   |   1   |
|  1   |    04/03/2021   |   2   |
|  1   |    10/04/2021   |   4   |
|  2   |    13/03/2021   |   3   |
|  3   |    01/03/2021   |   1   |
|  3   |    27/04/2021   |   3   |
|  4   |    21/02/2021   |   2   |
|  4   |    14/03/2021   |   3   |
|  4   |    01/04/2021   |   4   |
+------+-----------------+-------+
```

On a table like this, I want to know how many teams that have been visited X times and have medal Y.
So far, I can count how many teams where visited X times.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Team_Visit FROM
(SELECT TEAM FROM table GROUP BY TEAM HAVING COUNT(VISITS)=1);
```

With this, I know how many teams (it doesn't matter which ones) where visited once, twice, three times, and so on...
But now how do I know, for instance, from the ones that were visited once, how many have medal 1?

An expected result would be:

> How many teams, that were visited three times, have medal 2?

The answer would give me **2** (because both teams 1 and 4 were).

> Or how many teams, that were visited three times, have medal 3?

The answer would be **1** (because only team 4 was).

Should I use an inner join? Can I do it based on the query that I already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following. Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=73739cd0a5a7d7ab6fd8ade4fd0701c7).

```
with cte as
(
  select 
    team,
    medal,
    count(*) over (partition by team) as total_cnt
  from mytable
)
select
   count(distinct team) as total_teams
from cte
where total_cnt = 3
and medal = 2
```

Comment: Can I also filter by the visit date? If I want the same logic, but during a specific period?  (How many teams that were visited X times between >day w< and >day z<, have the medal Y). Kind of WHERE VISITS BETWEEN (any date) AND (another date). Where would I put it?

Comment: @lulu yes you can. just add visit date in subquery and then in final query add visit date range in where condition.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
select distinct sum(1) over () as total
from yourtable t1
where exists (select 1 from yourtable t2 where t2.medal = Y and t1.team = t2.team)
group by team
having count(*)  = X
```

Comment: I like this answer. But for `X = 3` and `Y = 2`, this query gives *two* rows with value `2`. Can that be fixed somehow?

Comment: @BartHofland add distinct

Comment: This is a clever query. I will go study it in some more detail, since I am not used to its logic. I am not that familiar with the behavior of windowing functions in such scenarios. Very nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce some variables:

- `@X` (the specific number of visits) and
- `@Y` (a specific earned medal).

```sql
DECLARE @X INT = 3;
DECLARE @Y INT = 2;
```

This query would get the teams that have a specific number of visits:

```sql
DECLARE @X INT = 3;
DECLARE @Y INT = 2;

SELECT TEAM
FROM table
GROUP BY TEAM
HAVING COUNT(*) = @X;
```

This query would get the teams that have a specific medal:

```sql
DECLARE @X INT = 3;
DECLARE @Y INT = 2;

SELECT TEAM
FROM table
WHERE MEDAL = @Y;
```

The query that gets the teams that have a specific number of visits cannot return duplicate values, but the query that gets the teams that have a specific medal could. So I would use the former as the base query, so that duplicates are automatically eliminated.

The second query could be combined in the first query like this:

```sql
DECLARE @X INT = 3;
DECLARE @Y INT = 2;

SELECT TEAM
FROM table
WHERE TEAM IN (SELECT TEAM
               FROM table
               WHERE MEDAL = @Y)
GROUP BY TEAM
HAVING COUNT(*) = @X;
```

However, you do not want the TEAM values themselves, but the number of teams. For this, you can wrap the entire query in a table expression and select the number of its resulting rows like this:

```sql
DECLARE @X INT = 3;
DECLARE @Y INT = 2;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT TEAM
      FROM table
      WHERE TEAM IN (SELECT TEAM
                     FROM table
                     WHERE MEDAL = @Y)
      GROUP BY TEAM
      HAVING COUNT(*) = @X) AS T;
```

**Edit:**

By the way, the global structure of the base query resembles the query in [eshirvana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67523905/4174789) very much. That query is a lot shorter, however, because another (actually pretty clever) mechanism for counting the number of matching teams is used there. You might want to go with that solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, perhaps simpler...

```
;with cte as 
    (select team, count(*) as visits
    from mytable
    group by team)
select count(c.team) 
    from mytable a
    join cte c on a.team=c.team
    where c.visits=3 and medal=2
```